# Dynamically changing height and width of ExtJS Panel with layout 'table'

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am creating dynamic table inside a panel. I want to set the height and width of the table dynamically (at runtime) based on few conditions. I am able to get the height and width of its parent container but I am unable to assign this height and width to the table. Here is my code:

```
var myComponent = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            layout: {
                type: 'table',
                columns: 3
            },
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (panel) {
                    var myWidth = panel.up('panel').getWidth();
                    var myHeight = panel.up('panel').getHeight();
                    panel.setHeight(myHeight);
                    panel.setWidth(myWidth);
                }
            },
            items: [{
                html: 'Widget 0',
                rowspan: 2
            }, {
                html: 'Widget 1',
                colspan: 2
            }, {
                html: 'Widget 2'
            }]
});
```

How to set the height and width of the dynamically created table?

Answer (score 0):

I think components with no content may not be displayed at all. Try adding a flex of 1, or perhaps setting MinHeight, MinWidth. Something along these lines will probably work.

Comment: I have already tried with 'flex', 'minHeight' and 'minWidth' but to no avail. Also, I have specified 'html' for the components.

Comment: Did you try to change the layout to see if it works?

Comment: Using a table layout is the only option since I have to create components dynamically with different height and width.

Comment: What happens when you try to get the height/width of the panel after it has been rendered?

Comment: The height and width can be obtained but it is not being assigned to the panel.